# Filter out all the rows with the same background color in Excel 2003?

Tags: excel

Now, I want to get all the rows with the same background color in a sheet. How do I filter out all the rows with the same background color in Excel 2003?

Updated:
[image]

I have added the function to my Excel, and the function is in the insert function which is under the "User Defined" category.

But I don't know how to use it. Now, if I want to show all the data with the same background color as the `A1:I1` on the sheet1, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Within a module you can add this function:

```
Function CellColour(rngIn As Range) As Long
Application.Volatile True
CellColour = rngIn(1).Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Then you recall it as a native formula

```
=CellColour(A1)
```

Apply it to the range you need and filter on the number returned by the formula.

Comment: i am sorry, i am a newbie of excel. i don't know where i should put the code in? thank you.

Comment: but i don't know how to use it. i have updated my question. thank you